Deploying Angular app to Azure Static Web Apps using Azure DevOps pipeline
When creating an Azure Static Web App in App Services, a CI/CD pipeline is automatically set up to run in GitHub Actions. However, we prefer to use Azure DevOps for our CI/CD processes. We have a project with a .NET Core backend and an Angular frontend, each housed in separate repositories. To start, we decided to focus on the frontend and created an Azure DevOps pipeline for it.
Azure Pipeline.yml
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  npm_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npmcache

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build and Test Stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "20.x"
            displayName: "Install Node.js"

          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package-lock.json'
              restoreKeys: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)"'
              path: $(npm_cache)
            displayName: Cache npm dependencies

          - script: |
              npm ci --cache $(npm_cache)
              npm install -g @angular/cli
            displayName: "Install dependencies"

          - script: |
              VERSION=$(grep -m1 '"version":' package.json | cut -d '"' -f4)
              echo "Detected Version: $VERSION"
              if [[ ! $VERSION =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                echo "Invalid version format. Must be X.Y.Z"
                exit 1
              fi
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectVersion;isoutput=true]$VERSION"
            name: setVersion
            displayName: "Set and Validate project version"

          - script: |
              ng build --configuration production
            displayName: "Build production"

          - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/angular-frontend/browser
            artifact: release-$(setVersion.projectVersion)
            displayName: "Publish build artifacts"

  - stage: Development
    displayName: "Deploy to Development"
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    variables:
      projectVersion: $[ stageDependencies.Build.Build.outputs['setVersion.projectVersion'] ]
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeploymentDevelopment
        environment: Dev
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - download: current
                  artifact: release-$(projectVersion)
                  displayName: "Download Artifacts"

                - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
                  inputs:
                    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
                    app_location: "/"
                    output_location: "dist/angular-frontend/browser"
                    skip_api_build: true
                    verbose: true
                  displayName: "Deploy to Azure Static Web App Dev"


At first we tried running on the self hosted agent in my local machine. in the self hosted agen it successfully deployed our app to azure static web app, When attempting to deploy using microsoft hosted agent to Azure Static Web Apps via Azure DevOps pipeline, the deployment fails with the error:
Detecting platforms...
Could not detect any platform in the source directory.
Error: Could not detect the language from repo.

and this is my project structure.
.
├── .angular/
├── .github/
├── dist/
│   └── angular-frontend
├── node_modules/
├── public/
├── src/
│   ├── app/
│   └── index.html
├── .editorconfig
├── .gitignore
├── angular.json
├── azure-pipeline.yml
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── README.MD
├── tsconfig.app.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── tsconfig.spec.json


Please share your code repo.

https://github.com/dinesh-nimmagadda3/angular-frontend.git
i haven't worked on this repo, just clean new angular app

How you are deploying your App?

we are trying to deploy using azure devops pipeline instead of github actions generated pipeline.

I am able to deploy the app without any issuesImage

Refer this MSDoc once

When using an Azure DevOps repository, everything works as expected. For GitHub repositories, it also works when registered as a static web app with GitHub Actions. However, if the GitHub Actions workflow is disabled and the same pipeline is executed through Azure DevOps, it fails. Notably, the pipeline works on a self-hosted machine but fails on a Microsoft-hosted agent.
